# Is "At Time Zone" a function? why the syntax is so different?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 has a new feature, [At time Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql). 
It can be used in SELECT

```
Select getDate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time'
```

and in WHERE

```
Select 1
Where getDate() at time zone 'Central Standard Time' > '2018-1-1'
```

Is it a function? why the syntax is So different from other functions?

Comment: It's not a function - it's a hint (similar to, for example, using `COLLATE` with a string).

Comment: @ZLK, can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It is a function that taps into the Windows Registry. Registry based functions are called in the manner of:

```
 RegistryFunctionName 'param1Value', 'param2Value', etc.
```

Sort of like how CLR function names are case sensitive whereas T-SQL function names are not. For more reading, see here:

http://www.sqlsolutionsgroup.com/working-registry-sql-server/

https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone

Comment: @Rm558 You might want to consider marking your question as answered.